# If I pressed "Start Progress" button on one issue can JIRA stop progress on other issues?

Tags: workflow, jira

Issue in JIRA have "Start Progress" button, which turns issue to "In progress" status.

If I pressed "Start Progress" button on one issue can JIRA stop progress on other issues?

Comment: Does the issue to be changed happen to be the parent of the issue you are starting progress on?

Comment: No. Their relationship is unimportant.

Comment: Then I think you'd probably have to write a custom plugin to handle that workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Jira Scripting](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/16346) Suite to write a post script that runs after `start progress` transition and change all other issues that are on `In progress` to a different status.

Let me know if you need help with coding that.

Comment: I think it can help. Thanks, I'll try and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: #user1329222 cool, if you're stuck you know where to find me :)